# How to create dynamic condition using Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, expression-trees

Please consider this code:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<tbl, bool>> exp_details = r => r.ID_Master == Id &&
r.Year == Year &&
r.Month == Month ;
```

I want to write a function that expect some argument, and then retrieve some data from my database. The problem is I want to create dynamic condition.dor example if I pass `IsDeleted` argument with `true` value I want to add `r.IsDeleted == true;` to `exp_details`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to doing this is to use an `ExpressionVisitor` which walks the given expression and (optionally, in a subclass) allows for replacing recognized elements with others you specify. In my case this was done for ORM (NHibernate). This is what I use: (I'll add references to my answer later)

```
public class ParameterAssignAndReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _source;
    private readonly ConstantExpression _target;

    internal ParameterAssignAndReplacer(ParameterExpression source, ConstantExpression target)
    {
        _source = source;
        _target = target;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node.Name == _source.Name ?
            base.VisitConstant(_target) :
            base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

And..

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<TArg2, TResult>> AssignAndReduce<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>(
        this Expression<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TResult>> func,
        TArg1 parameter)
    {
        var exprBody = func.Body;
        var assignedParameter = Expression.Constant(parameter, typeof(TArg1));
        exprBody = new ParameterAssignAndReplacer(func.Parameters[0], assignedParameter).Visit(exprBody);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg2, TResult>>(exprBody, func.Parameters[1]);
    }
}
```

Both classes can be extended to your specific scenario. To make this relevant to the code you posted (I'm using only `IsDeleted` as the parameter for simplicity):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    Expression<Func<tbl, bool, bool>> _templateExpression =
       (tbl r, bool isDeleted) => r.ID_Master == 5 && r.Year == 2008 && r.Month == 12 && r.IsDeleted == isDeleted;

    public Expression<Func<tbl, bool>> Foo(bool IsDeleted)
    {
        return _templateExpression.AssignAndReduce(IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

Regarding references, most of what I learned on this topic is from [Marc Gravell's "Expressions" answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:23354%20%5Bexpression-trees%5D) [ although many other users have helped me get a grip on this :-) ]

Comment: you soltion is complex.Isn't there any simple solution?

Comment: Prior to .net 4.0 you'd have to work a lot harder - expression visitor is now part of the framework. If all you want to do is just use True or False I would hardcore the different expressions and use if-else. If it's more generic I would advise to use this or a similar approach. All you are looking at here are one extra class and one method..

Comment: 2. I think I switched TArg1 and TArg2 in AssignAndReduce() 3. Once you see the debug-visualizer in VS give you the reduced Expression you begin to realize how powerful expression trees are in C#... Anyway i hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

you can't use statement body to Linq Expression
consider using Predicate instead

```
        var exp_details = new Predicate<tbl>(r =>
        {
            bool result == Id && r.Year == Year && r.Month == Month;
            if(IsDeleted != null)
            {
                result &= r.IsDeleted == IsDeleted;
            }
            return result;
        });
```

the most Linq **Func<T, bool>** expression can be replaced with **Predicate<T>**.

### To generate dynamic WHERE cause using "simple" linq expression.

```
IQueryable<tbl> query = ent.tbl.Where(r => r.ID_Master == Id && r.Year == Year);
//customize query
if(IsDeleted != null){
  query = query.Where(r => r.IsDeleted == IsDeleted);
}
//execute the final generated query
var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

this will create where cause from `IQueryable<T>`. Linq is smart enough for complex query.

Comment: can I use `Predicate` this way: `ent.tbl.Where(exp).FirstOrDefault();` does `Predicate` tranlate to where clause in generated query?

Comment: you can but it select all items into memory then filter each record by delegate function. alternately, using **PredicateBuilder** [link](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) will generate SQL WHERE cause.